# OpenAm authentication

Tags: policy, openam, opensso

I am trying to implement third party authentication with openAM, and have a doubt regarding openAm implementation, i.e if my application is distributed under different servers which are geographically separated and controlled under the same DNS name. How can I differentiate the sessions of different server. Say for example if I type www.google.com it can forward to any of the nearest server available, now if I have to authenticate google.com how will my openAm know that the request is for that particular server.  If I ask it in other way, so whenever we are changing a policy in openam or invalidating a session it callbacks to all the registered server, now in distributed environment how it can differentiate the server IP's

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have some sort of LB in front of you servers. I would suggest creating a sticky session at the LB, like a cookie saying what server the user is on before starting the authentication. Then when authentication i done, openam redirects back to your LB and the LB directs to the correct server.

Comment: in that case if admin invalidates the session how the agent will be call backed because the openam will not know this session is for which server behind load balancer

Comment: So your question is. If the administrator in OpenAM invalidates a users session, how will the correct server be notified of this? Correct? The agent at the servers will check back with OpenAM for every user request. If the openam session has been invalidated the agent will redirect the user to the loginpage again.